# cin.ignore equivalent in `ncurses`

Tags: c++, ncurses

I have this much cleaner variant to `system("Pause")` that waits for the user to press enter:

```
#include <iostream>
void pause()
{
    std::cin.get();
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

However, I couldn't find a clean variant to `system("CLS")` (or `system("clear")`), so I switched the whole application to `ncurses`.
After some reading I found out that `ncurses` has its own set of I/O functions and that `std::cout` and `std::cin` got replaced with `echo()` and `getch()`.

That function `pause()` also has to be converted to `ncurses`, but my problem is that I don't know the correct equivalent to `std::cin.ignore`.

Comment: Off topic: You may find `void pause() { std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); }` a wee bit more reliable if you only want to exit on enter. Your version may leave crap in the stream to be picked up by subsequent stream reads.

Comment: Can you not use `getch()` itself to achieve the effect of `pause()`? You'd want to call `noecho()` before `getch()` to hide the input character.

Answer (score 0):

You can discard input in curses using these functions (not just ncurses):

- [**`flushinp`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-flushinp)

  > The  **`flushinp`**  routine throws away any typeahead that has been typed by
  >      the user and has not yet been read by the program.
- [**`intrflush`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-intrflush)

  > If  the  **`intrflush`** option is enabled (*bf* is TRUE), and an interrupt key
  >   is pressed on the keyboard (interrupt, break, quit), all output in  the
  >   tty  driver queue will be flushed, giving the effect of faster response
  >   to the interrupt, but causing curses to have the wrong idea of what  is
  >   on  the screen.  Disabling the option (*bf* is FALSE) prevents the flush.
  >   The default for the option is inherited from the tty  driver  settings.
  >   The window argument is ignored.